# Mapster thinks my property access in lambda is not property access

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapster

I have two way config for mapping using `Mapster`:

```
public static TwoWaysTypeAdapterSetter<Client, Models.ClientAggregate.Client> ClientConfig =>
    TypeAdapterConfig<Client, Models.ClientAggregate.Client>
    .NewConfig()
    .TwoWays()
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedGrantTypes, src => src.GrantTypes.Select(p => p.Type))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedRedirectUris, src => src.RedirectUris.Select(p => p.Uri))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedAuthorizationDetailSchemas, src => src.Actions.GroupBy(p => p.AuthorizationDetailSchema.Type)
        .Select(p => new Models.ClientAggregate.ClientAllowedSchema
        {
            SchemaType = p.Key,
            AllowedActions = p.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
        }))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedClaims, src => src.Claims.Select(p => p.Type));
```

Later I use it as below:

```
public async Task<Models.ClientAggregate.Client?> FindEnabledByClientIdAsync(string clientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return await _dbContext.Clients.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
        .ProjectToType<Models.ClientAggregate.Client>(MappingConfigs.ClientConfig.SourceToDestinationSetter.Config)
        .Where(p => p.ClientId == clientId && p.Enabled)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

And don't know why, I get the exception:

> ArgumentException: Allow only member access (eg. obj => obj.Child.Name) (Parameter 'lambda')

You see that all of my destinations in mapping are property accessors. What causes the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least remove `TwoWays()` which literally results in defining mapping in [two ways](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Two-ways#2-ways-mapping) (i.e. both direct and reverse mapping):

> If you need to map object from POCO to DTO, and map back from DTO to POCO. You can define the setting once by using `TwoWays`.

So the resulting mapping should be:

```cs
public static TwoWaysTypeAdapterSetter<Client, Models.ClientAggregate.Client> ClientConfig =>
    TypeAdapterConfig<Client, Models.ClientAggregate.Client>
    .NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedGrantTypes, src => src.GrantTypes.Select(p => p.Type))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedRedirectUris, src => src.RedirectUris.Select(p => p.Uri))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedAuthorizationDetailSchemas, src => src.Actions.GroupBy(p => p.AuthorizationDetailSchema.Type)
        .Select(p => new Models.ClientAggregate.ClientAllowedSchema
        {
            SchemaType = p.Key,
            AllowedActions = p.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
        }))
    .Map(dest => dest.AllowedClaims, src => src.Claims.Select(p => p.Type));
```

The `dest` expressions will become source ones for reverse mapping, and they are clearly not a member access expressions, hence the exception.

Comment: Thought about it today. Thank you!